# Prior Art existing

Tags: search

In reference to the patent: [US8230232](https://www.google.com/patents/US8230232)

How can it be that this patent was granted if there is http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-44871-6_29#page-1 and  http://www.google.com/patents/US5557686

Comment: springer article was published on JUne 4-6, 2003; USpatent in question has priority of May 2 2003; for second art it seems to be Keystroke and Biometric definitions are different and keystroke might not anticipate Biometric verification.

Answer (score 1):

Springer article was published on June 4-6, 2003; US patent in question has priority of May 2 2003;

for second art it seems to be Keystroke and Biometric definitions are different and keystroke might not anticipate Biometric verification

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about, what is counting. But the latest submission date for the conference papers was Dec. 2002. http://www.aerfai.es/media/uploads/ibpria03/homepage.html

Comment: you are right that publication last date of submitting paper was december 2002 but publication was not done befor june 2003, i urge you to contact author if he made any publication before.